# ST_DIFFERENCE returning GeometryCollection instead of MultiPoint

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to get the difference between two multipoints.  I am doing this using the query `location = ST_Difference(location, other_geo)`.  This works when the result is not empty, however, if the two multipoints are exactly the same, the resulting object is a `GeometryCollection` instead of an empty MultiPoint, as would be returned from `ST_geomFromText('MULTIPOINT EMPTY')`.  How do I get the result to be an empty multipoint object?

The following query results in a multipoint:

`SELECT ST_asGeoJSON(ST_Difference(ST_geomFromText('MultiPoint(1 2, 3 4)', 4326), ST_geomFromText('MultiPoint(1 2)', 4326)));`

Result: `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,4]}`

This one results in an empty `GeometryCollection`:

`SELECT ST_asGeoJSON(ST_Difference(ST_geomFromText('MultiPoint(1 2)', 4326), ST_geomFromText('MultiPoint(1 2)', 4326)));`

Result: `{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[]}`

Comment: Wrapping the `ST_Difference` in `ST_CollectionExtract( ____ , 1)` returns an empty multipoint and a multipoint for when there are more than 1 point returned, but on 1 point is normalizes it to a `Point`, so that won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ST_Multi and ST_CollectionExtract to always return a MultiPoint geometry with zero or more points:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Multi(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Difference(a, b), 1)))
FROM (
  SELECT 'MultiPoint(1 2, 3 4)'::geometry a, 'MultiPoint(1 2)'::geometry b
  UNION SELECT 'MultiPoint(1 2)', 'MultiPoint(1 2)'
) data;
                st_asgeojson
---------------------------------------------
 {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[]}
 {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[3,4]]}
(2 rows)
```